# At high load getting "Received invalid metadata error in produce request " kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, vert.x, kafka-producer-api

I have a producer writing a million messages in loop to kafka. After processing around half million messages (not exact, varies in different runs) it starts giving

*Received invalid metadata error in produce request  on partition TEST-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.. Going to request metadata update now.* After this my producer stops responding and i only have option to kill the process.

I have not changed much in the kafka producer configurations but not sure ideally what should I change. I have updated following properties

1. **acks = "all"**
2. **max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1**
3. **retries = 3**
4. **request.timeout.ms = 20000**
5. **retry.backoff.ms=1000**
6. **linger.ms=5**
7. **batch.size=25600**

It seems to me that the producer is sending message to Kafka continuously but not getting response back. Also, another message that i am getting is with above is *Group coordinator IP_of_kafka_server  is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery*

PS:

I am using kafka-0.11, one message is around 20000 characters and brokers have enough space to accomodate all messages. Replication factor for the topic is 1 (since doing testing) and my cluster have 3 brokers.

Comment: You could try lowering the batch size. Otherwise, what type of monitoring do you have on the brokers other than the logs? Can you expose JMX data and see any outliers?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have JMX port enabled, but there i can just see sudden spike in CPU and then that reduces which i think is because the producer is not able to receive response from brokers.  Also, I had increased batch size after i saw various posts on internet to use batch size to increase throughput. Not sure where i am going wrong

Comment: Cpu spike on the client? What about the brokers?

Comment: @cricket_007 For brokers i can see spike in read/writes bytes of around 15 Million. And CPU spiked from 1% to 8%

Comment: That doesn't seem significant... Have you tried ack=1 and more retries?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i had tried with ack=1 as well, but still no luck. Faced same errors including "Group Coordinator unavailable". Also, i thought 3 retries are enough as i feel the coordinator is burdened with the request and increasing retries will only worsen the problem, i was even thinking of reducing this. Do let me know if i am wrong.
Also, since i have a feeling that brokers are burdened with requests is there a way to control the flow of requests to a certain limit? (I know we can always wait before sending the request from producer but i don't want to make the code blocking)

Comment: `linger.ms` does cause the producer to wait before sending data, by the way. And you can set throttles on the brokers / topics, but I don't know if that answers your question. In general, see you have some timeout issues somewhere, or the network is flaky

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same problem right now, the producer just stops sending messages after this error happens.

Comment: Any success with that problem?